# Why does it not work? StartupLocation = CenterOwner in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

[image]

I want to locate my sub window to center of parent window. But it is not working in WPF.

I set `StartupLocation  = CenterOwner`. But it is not working.

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() => new TestWindow().ShowDialog());
        });
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp29.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp29"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

TestWindow.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class TestWindow : Window
    {
        public TestWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

TestWindow.xaml

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfApp29.TestWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp29"
            WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="TestWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I call `ShowDialog` function in `MainWindow`. But `Testwindow` is not located to `CenterOwner` (`MainWindow`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the `Owner` of your TestWindow to the MainWindow like:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        TestWindow testWindow = new TestWindow();
        testWindow.Owner = this;
        testWindow.ShowDialog();
    });
});
```

Otherwise the Owner of your TestWindow is null and than the TestWindow will open at a "random" location.

Comment: Working well. Thank you.